# In Python how to add or insert tab (\t) into list

Tags: python, list, tabs

I am new to python. I am trying to add a /t to a string variable and insert in to a list.
when I print the string, it prints with space.
When the same variable added/inserted to the list it prints \t. how to fix it.
Same works if if add space.
Please help me.

Code:

```py
str1 = "new_service_group"
src_grp = "servicegroups\t\t\t\t" + str1
print("src_grp is = " + src_grp)
array = [
    'define service{',
    'host_name               host-a1p',
    'service_description     Disk Space /var',
    'use                     ch_rating_system',
    '}'
]
array.insert(len(array) - 1, src_grp)
print(array)
```

Output:

```
src_grp is = servicegroups              new_service_group
['define service{', 'host_name               host-a1p', 'service_description     Disk Space /var', 'use                     ch_rating_system', 'servicegroups\t\t\t\tnew_service_group', '}']
```

But I expect "servicegroups             new_service_group"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str1="new_service_group"
src_grp="servicegroups\t\t\t\t"+str1
print("src_grp is = "+src_grp)
array=['define service{', 'host_name               host-a1p', 'service_description     Disk Space /var', 'use                     ch_rating_system', '}']
array.insert(len(array)-1,src_grp.expandtabs())
print(array)
```

Use the `expandtabs()` method on your element for the tabs to print correctly
When you print element from a list, you use the repr method of the list object, not the one of the String object which is different.

Note that by doing expandtabs() on the object before adding it to the list, you are actually modifying the string added to the list by replacing `/t` by the space equivalent.